# How to access a Streamlit app from a Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, streamlit

I am running a basic Streamlit chatbot in a docker container. After running the docker container I get the following in my terminal.

```
Collecting usage statistics. To deactivate, set browser.gatherUsageStats to False.

  You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

  Network URL: http://172.17.0.2:8501
  External URL: http://49.36.212.205:8501
```

Now if I try to open http:/localhost:8051/ I get the following.

[image: Error Message]

This problem does not occur when I run my Streamlit app locally (without Docker).

[image: Local Run]

Following the content of my Dockerfile.

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8501

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser

WORKDIR /home/appuser/app
COPY main.py /home/appuser/app

RUN chown -R appuser /home/appuser/app

USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
ENTRYPOINT [ "streamlit", "run" ]
CMD ["main.py"]
```

Following are the commands that I used to build the image and run the container.

```
docker build -t test_streamlit . -f Dockerfile
docker run -p 8051:8051 --name test-1 test_streamlit
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your app is binding to the container IP (`172.17.0.2`) and when you try access `localhost` it resolves to `127.0.0.1`, but your app isn't listening on that address.

To make an app work from inside a container, it needs to bind to all addresses (`0.0.0.0`). Not sure how your app works, but see if there's an option somewhere to change the bind address to `0.0.0.0` - that should do the trick.

Comment: I update the dockerfile to bind the address as you suggested CMD streamlit run main.py \
    --server.headless true \
    --browser.serverAddress="0.0.0.0" \
    --server.enableCORS false \
    --browser.gatherUsageStats false. And now when I run the container I can see in the output URL: http://0.0.0.0:8501. But still I am not able to access the chatbot in m local when open the url.

Comment: Your `docker run` command forwards port `8051`, but the app is running on port `8501`. Looks like a typo. Try changing the docker command to use `-p 8501:8501` instead and see if you can access `localhost:8501`.

Comment: Yup that was the problem. It fixed now thanks :)